# Is it possible to disable x & z rotation in ammo.js?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, physics

Well, Is it possible to disable x & z rotation in ammo.js?
(I want to create a FPS Player and I want to keep it in vertical position)

Comment: I live by the philosophy that anything is possible just how deep down the rabbit hole do you want to go? :P

Comment: I'd like not to edit the source code...

Answer (score 3):

In bullet there is btRigidBody::setAngularFactor which takes a btVector3 as argument, where x, y and z corresponds to rotation along those axis. Use a 1 to allow motion, and 0 to disallow motion along a certain axis.

If you want to allow **rotation only along the Y axis** in ammo.js, use:

```
body.setAngularFactor( 0, 1, 0 );
```

See http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Code_Snippets